# How disable NOUVEAU?

Tags: nouveau

1. I edit blacklist.conf
   [blacklist.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xllA.png)
2. I look what kernel modules are currently loaded [nouveau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG54e.png)

Update_1:

> lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
Subsystem: Pegatron Device 20c6
Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 640M] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Pegatron Device 20c6
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Update_2:
Edited this file:

> /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    DefaultDepth    24
EndSection        

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Default Device"
    Driver  "nvidia"
    Option  "NoLogo"    "True"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load    "glx"
EndSection
```

> lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Pegatron Device 20c6
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 640M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Pegatron Device 20c6
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: did you reboot the system after? and what are you trying to do exactly? To use *nvidia* instead of *nouveau* ?

Comment: Why do you want to disable nouveau? You probably need to install proprietary drivers instead. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: yes, I rebooted the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile Nvidia GPU's cause headache because they are used with VGA controller which is embedded in Intel CPUs, as named Optimus Technology.
I am able to activate Nvidia driver with editing /etc/X11/xorg.conf file after installation driver with apt-get, just installing nvidia driver by apt-get may not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Nvidia drivers by running:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```